# How to make timestamp date column into preferred format dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: date, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a column `YDate` in the form `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (timestamp type) but would like to convert it to `dd/MM/yyyy`.

I tried that;

```
df = df.withColumn('YDate',F.to_date(F.col('YDate'),'dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

but get `yyyy-MM-dd`.

How can I effectively do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date_format` instead:

```
df = df.withColumn('YDate',F.date_format(F.col('YDate'),'dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

`to_date` converts **from** the given format, while `date_format` converts **into** the given format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_format` function present in the pyspark library.
For more information about date formats you can refer to [Date Format Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format).

Below is the code snippet to solve your usecase.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('2015-12-28 23:59:59',)], ['YDate'])
df = df.withColumn('YDate', F.date_format('YDate', 'dd/MM/yyy'))
```